# Cannot add foreign key constraint in SQL

Tags: sqlfiddle

I have been reading through this forum trying to find the right things to solve my question but I cannot find any answers. I have tweaked my code so much to make sure that the issue is really with adding a foreign key.

My tables are created before I made the foreign key and they are not referencing each out. What is going on?

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    LName varchar(200),
    FName varchar(200),
    StreetAdd varchar(200),
    City varchar(100),
    State varchar(100),
    Zip integer,
    Phone bigint
);

CREATE TABLE Donut (
  DonutID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(100),
  Description varchar(200),
  UnitPrice float(2)
);

CREATE TABLE Invoice(
  Quantity smallint,
  OrderID integer,
  DonutID integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES DOrder(OrderID),
  FOREIGN KEY (DonutID) REFERENCES Donut(DonutID)
);

CREATE TABLE DOrder (
    OrderID integer NOT NULL,
    OrderDat integer,
    Notes varchar(400),
    CustomerID integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID)
);
```

Comment: Could you add a link to your fiddle? What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: You need to create DOrder before you create Invoice. Or just run the script twice so DOrder already exists before you attempt foreign key references.

Comment: @ooXei1sh you are a life saver this is why some days I question why I am going into coding. I completely over looked the last 4 hours that I reference dorder before it was made. I can now stop going crazy.